# Handling bad records in spark select statement

Tags: apache-spark

I have a Seq[Column] to select from a dataframe. Some of the columns can be udfs so there might be a column which selects a string column and tries to convert it to a double. Sometimes this column might be null.

Is it possible to catch records which throw an exception return a dataframe of records which could be processed correctly instead of killing the processing of the entire dataframe.
At the moment I have the below code, if price is null for a single row the whole operation will fail. I would like it to process all other rows

```scala
 def stringToLong(s: String): BigDecimal = s.toLong
 def stringToBigLongUdf: UserDefinedFunction = udf(stringToLong _)
 df.select(stringToLongUdf(new Column("price")))
```

Comment: Your code does not compile. Also, I don't fully understand what you mean by "records which don't have the column". Dataframes are tables and all records have value (even if it is None or null) for all columns. Can you provide more details. Maybe some sample data and expected output?

Comment: Is that better ?

Comment: Could you provide an example of such an UDF column and the error that it throws? Type conversion usually passes nulls through and UDFs can be written to gracefully handle them too.

Comment: Not really better. It would be very helpful if you could provide a minimal instance of your problem, with code and data so that we can reproduce it and better understand what you are trying to do. It may even help you find a solution yourself. Your code still does not compile btw.

Comment: Try `select(columns :_*)` ;-)

Comment: Is it better now?

Answer (score 0):

Here is how your UDF should handle the exception and return None for error

```
import scala.util.{Try, Success, Failure}
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.UserDefinedFunction
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

def stringToLong(s: String): Option[BigDecimal] = {
  Try(s.toLong) match {
    case Success(v) => Some(v)
    case Failure(_) => None 
  }
}

def stringToBigLongUdf: UserDefinedFunction = udf(stringToLong _)
val df = Seq("111", "23d", "456").toDF("price")
df.select(stringToBigLongUdf(col("price"))).show
```